# Writing NA when exporting from R to Excel format

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has a lot of NA and numbers. 
When exporting to Excel using write.xlsx2, the output Excel file has empty cells for NA values. 
I tried

```
write.xlsx2(mydataframe, "foo.xlsx", sheetName = "foo1", showNA = T, append=F)
```

But the output still shows NA as empty cells. Why isn't showNA argument working?

Comment: I think only `write.xlsx` is affected by the `showNA` argument, while `write.xlsx2` is not.

Comment: Another option would be to do the following: `wb = createWorkbook(); sheet=createSheet(wb, "my sheet"); addDataFrame(mydataframe, sheet=sheet, showNA=TRUE); saveWorkbook(wb, "foo.xlsx")`. To put multiple sheets in the same workbook, just repeat `createSheet(); addDataFrame()` for each data frame, which can be done in a loop. Then save at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like that argument is not passed to addDataFrame.  Not sure if that's a bug or a design decision.

https://github.com/cran/xlsx/blob/master/R/write.xlsx2.R

Comment: as eipi10 suggested, I can still use write.xlsx but it takes longer to write the excel file...